# BeatuifulSoup iterate over 10 k pages & fetch data, parse: European Volunteering-Services: a tiny scraper that collects opportunities from EU-Site

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am looking for a public list of Volunteering - Services in Europe: I don't need full addresses - but the name and the website. I think of data ... XML, CSV ... with these fields: name, country - and some additional fields would be nice one record per country of presence. **btw:** the european volunteering services are great options for the youth

well I  have found a great page that is very very comprehensive - see

want to gather data from the **european volunteering services** that are hosted on a European site:

https://youth.europa.eu/go-abroad/volunteering/opportunities_en

We have got several hundred volunteering opportunities there - which are stored in sites like the following:

```
 https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/39020_en 

https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38993_en 

https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38973_en 

https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38972_en 

https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38850_en 

https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38633_en
```

**idea:**

I think it would be awesome to gather the data - i.e. with a scraper that is based on `BS4` and `requests` - parsing the data and subsequently printing the data in a `dataframe`

Well - I think that we could iterate over all the urls:

```
placement/39020_en 
placement/38993_en 
placement/38973_en 
placement/38850_en
```

**UPDATE:** thanks to @hedgeHog s help we ve got a solution.

**idea**:  I think that we can iterate from zero to 100 000 in stored to fetch all the results  that are stored in placements. But this idea is not backed with a code. In other words - at the moment I do not have an idea how to do this special idea of iterating over such a great range:

At the moment I think - it is a basic approach to start with this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Function to generate placement URLs based on a range of IDs
def generate_urls(start_id, end_id):
    base_url = "https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/"
    urls = [base_url + str(id) + "_en" for id in range(start_id, end_id+1)]
    return urls

# Function to scrape data from a single URL
def scrape_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        title = soup.h1.get_text(', ', strip=True)
        location = soup.select_one('p:has(i.fa-location-arrow)').get_text(', ', strip=True)
        start_date, end_date = (e.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select('span.extra strong')[-2:])
        website_tag = soup.find("a", class_="btn__link--website")
        website = website_tag.get("href") if website_tag else None
        return {
            "Title": title,
            "Location": location,
            "Start Date": start_date,
            "End Date": end_date,
            "Website": website,
            "URL": url
        }
    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch data from {url}. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        return None

# Set the range of placement IDs we want to scrape
start_id = 1
end_id = 100000

# Generate placement URLs
urls = generate_urls(start_id, end_id)

# Scrape data from all URLs
data = []
for url in urls:
    placement_data = scrape_data(url)
    if placement_data:
        data.append(placement_data)

# Convert data to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print DataFrame
print(df)
```

which gives me back the following

```
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/154_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/156_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/157_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/159_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/161_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/162_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/163_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/165_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/166_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/169_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/170_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/171_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/173_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/174_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/176_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/177_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/178_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/179_en. Status code: 404
Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/180_en. Status code: 404
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d6272ee535ef> in <cell line: 42>()
     41 data = []
     42 for url in urls:
---> 43     placement_data = scrape_data(url)
     44     if placement_data:
     45         data.append(placement_data)

<ipython-input-5-d6272ee535ef> in scrape_data(url)
     16         title = soup.h1.get_text(', ', strip=True)
     17         location = soup.select_one('p:has(i.fa-location-arrow)').get_text(', ', strip=True)
---> 18         start_date, end_date = (e.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select('span.extra strong')[-2:])
     19         website_tag = soup.find("a", class_="btn__link--website")
     20         website = website_tag.get("href") if website_tag else None

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Any idea?

Comment: `soup.find("span", class_="field--name-field-placement-location")` did not find a matching element, so it returned `None`.

Comment: hi there dear John Gordon -  thanks alot: Now if we want to gather results of the sume of all the placements - see the various urls we have used above note: what if we iterate in the placements from zero to 100000 - and parse all the pages that are "real" pages - we need to gather all the data - and therefore we iterate over the set of urls so we do not parse only these ones - but all we can get "youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/39020_en", "youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38993_en", "youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38973_en", -- well see above the results... i got back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check whether the elements you want to select are contained in `response` / `soup`; the ones you are addressing do not appear to be present. So as mentioned by @John Gordon your selection is not finding anything.

You could select your elements like this - used [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) here:

```
# Extracting relevant data
title = soup.h1.get_text(', ',strip=True)
location = soup.select_one('p:has(i.fa-location-arrow)').get_text(', ',strip=True)
start_date,end_date = (e.get_text(strip=True)for e in soup.select('span.extra strong')[-2:])
```

|  | Title | Location | Start Date | End Date | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Supporting GOB's Sustainable Gardening Project "Es Viver" | c/ Camí des Castell, 53, 07702 Maó, Menorca, Spain | 01/06/2024 | 31/05/2025 | https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/39020_en |
| 1 | EUROPEAN VOLUNTEERING VS DEPOPULATION 3.0 | 47400 Medina del Campo (VALLADOLID), Spain | 31/05/2024 | 30/03/2025 | https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38993_en |
| 2 | SUPPORTING LOCAL COMMUNITIES: ASMISAF/AUNA Inclusión | Gandia, Spain | 01/06/2024 | 30/06/2025 | https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38973_en |
| 3 | SUPPORTING LOCAL COMMUNITIES: Caritas Gandia | Gandia, Spain | 01/06/2024 | 30/06/2025 | https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38972_en |
| 4 | Pedagogic farm based on equine assisted interventions + social service | Masía Cal Taulé s/n, 08673 Serrateix, Spain | 01/03/2024 | 31/03/2025 | https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38850_en |
| 5 | Suporting in a Rural Area | Plaza de Tuy, 6, 34440 Frómista, Spain | 04/03/2024 | 04/11/2024 | https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38633_en |

Comment: hi there dear HedgeHog - just awesome: i am just overwhelmed. Many many thanks. this is like a deep dive in python. I am trying to recapitulate all the steps you do. Many many thanks again

Comment: hi dear HedgeHog: thanks alot: Now if we want to gather results of the sume of all the placements - see the various urls we have used above note: what if we iterate in the placements from zero to 100000 - and parse all the pages that are "real" pages - we need to gather all the data - and therefore we iterate over the set of urls so we do not parse only these ones - but all we can get "youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/39020_en", "youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38993_en", "youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38973_en", -- well see above the results... i got back

Comment: To keep focus of  answers and your original question clean, this would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus - May roll back the changes you made for addressing the new issue and drop the link to your new question here. Thanks

Comment: hi there dear HegeHog - many many thanks for the quick reply - i ll do so later the day. At the moment i am in a hurry.  But i come back  and will  do as adviced. Untill later...

Comment: dear HedgeHog - many thanks for the hint - well i did not fully roll back here - but i will do this later the evening - at the moment i have set up a new question here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78162074/iterate-over-10-k-pages-fetch-data-parse-european-volunteering-services-tin