# iterate over 10 k pages & fetch data, parse: European Volunteering-Services: tiny scraper that collects opportunities from EU-Site

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am looking for a public list of Volunteering - Services in Europe: I don't need full addresses - but the name and the website. I think of data ...
XML, CSV ... with these fields: name, country - and some additional fields would be nice one record per country of presence.  **btw:** the european volunteering services are great options for the youth

well I  have found a great page that is very very comprehensive;
want to gather data from the **european volunteering services** that are hosted on a European site:

see:  https://youth.europa.eu/go-abroad/volunteering/opportunities_en

@HedgeHog showed me the right approach and how to find the correct selectors
in this thread: [BeatuifulSoup iterate over 10 k pages & fetch data, parse: European Volunteering-Services: a tiny scraper that collects opportunities from EU-Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78154925/beatuifulsoup-iterate-over-10-k-pages-fetch-data-parse-european-volunteering)

```
# Extracting relevant data
title = soup.h1.get_text(', ',strip=True)
location = soup.select_one('p:has(i.fa-location-arrow)').get_text(', ',strip=True)
start_date,end_date = (e.get_text(strip=True)for e in soup.select('span.extra strong')[-2:])
```

but we have got several hundred volunteering opportunities there - which are stored in sites like the following:

```
 https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/39020_en 

https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38993_en 

https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38973_en 

https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38972_en 

https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38850_en 

https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/38633_en
```

**idea:**

I think it would be awesome to gather the data - i.e. with a scraper that is based on `BS4` and `requests` - parsing the data and subsequently printing the data in a `dataframe`

Well - I think that we could iterate over all the urls:

```
placement/39020_en 
placement/38993_en 
placement/38973_en 
placement/38850_en
```

**idea**:  I think that we can iterate from zero to 100 000 in stored to fetch all the results  that are stored in placements.
But this idea is not backed with a code. In other words - at the moment I do not have an idea how to do this special idea of iterating over such a great range:

At the moment I think - it is a basic approach to start with this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Function to generate placement URLs based on a range of IDs
def generate_urls(start_id, end_id):
    base_url = "https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/"
    urls = [base_url + str(id) + "_en" for id in range(start_id, end_id+1)]
    return urls

# Function to scrape data from a single URL
def scrape_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        title = soup.h1.get_text(', ', strip=True)
        location = soup.select_one('p:has(i.fa-location-arrow)').get_text(', ', strip=True)
        start_date, end_date = (e.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select('span.extra strong')[-2:])
        website_tag = soup.find("a", class_="btn__link--website")
        website = website_tag.get("href") if website_tag else None
        return {
            "Title": title,
            "Location": location,
            "Start Date": start_date,
            "End Date": end_date,
            "Website": website,
            "URL": url
        }
    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch data from {url}. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        return None

# Set the range of placement IDs we want to scrape
start_id = 1
end_id = 100000

# Generate placement URLs
urls = generate_urls(start_id, end_id)

# Scrape data from all URLs
data = []
for url in urls:
    placement_data = scrape_data(url)
    if placement_data:
        data.append(placement_data)

# Convert data to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print DataFrame
print(df)
```

which gives me back the following

```
 Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/154_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/156_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/157_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/159_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/161_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/162_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/163_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/165_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/166_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/169_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/170_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/171_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/173_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/174_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/176_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/177_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/178_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/179_en. Status code: 404
    Failed to fetch data from https://youth.europa.eu/solidarity/placement/180_en. Status code: 404
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-5-d6272ee535ef> in <cell line: 42>()
         41 data = []
         42 for url in urls:
    ---> 43     placement_data = scrape_data(url)
         44     if placement_data:
         45         data.append(placement_data)
    
    <ipython-input-5-d6272ee535ef> in scrape_data(url)
         16         title = soup.h1.get_text(', ', strip=True)
         17         location = soup.select_one('p:has(i.fa-location-arrow)').get_text(', ', strip=True)
    ---> 18         start_date, end_date = (e.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select('span.extra strong')[-2:])
         19         website_tag = soup.find("a", class_="btn__link--website")
         20         website = website_tag.get("href") if website_tag else None
    
    ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Any idea?

see the bas-url: https://youth.europa.eu/go-abroad/volunteering/opportunities_en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating ids by yourself, I would rather choose the API approach and retrieve the information already structured as JSON. This could be converted into a `dataframe` via [`pandas.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

###### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

data = requests.get('https://youth.europa.eu/d8/api/rest/eyp/v1/search_en?type=Opportunity&size=100&from=0&filters%5Bstatus%5D=open&filters%5Bdate_end%5D%5Boperator%5D=%3E%3D&filters%5Bdate_end%5D%5Bvalue%5D=2024-03-14&filters%5Bdate_end%5D%5Btype%5D=must').json().get('hits').get('hits')
pd.json_normalize(data)
```

---

Simply check network tab of your browsers [dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network) to get an idea where the data comes from and how you could filter the results by payload:

```
type: Opportunity
size: 1000
from: 0
filters[status]: open
filters[date_end][operator]: >=
filters[date_end][value]: 2024-03-14
filters[date_end][type]: must
```

Comment: good day dear HedgeHog - many many thanks for the reply: i love to "choose the API approach and retrieve the data and the information" - i will digg deeper into all that. Many many thanks for your awesome help!! - greetings LeBrochet ;)

Answer (score 0):

tanks to your help and idea dear HedgeHog  - here the full solution that works propperly

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# Function to fetch data from the API and convert it into a DataFrame
def fetch_data():
    url = 'https://youth.europa.eu/d8/api/rest/eyp/v1/search_en?type=Opportunity&size=100&from=0&filters%5Bstatus%5D=open&filters%5Bdate_end%5D%5Boperator%5D=%3E%3D&filters%5Bdate_end%5D%5Bvalue%5D=2024-03-14&filters%5Bdate_end%5D%5Btype%5D=must'
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json().get('hits').get('hits')
        df = pd.json_normalize(data)
        return df
    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch data from the API. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        return None

# Fetch data from the API
df = fetch_data()

# Store DataFrame in a CSV file
if df is not None:
    df.to_csv('volunteering_opportunities.csv', index=False)
    print("DataFrame successfully stored in 'volunteering_opportunities.csv'")
```

it gives badk a csv based dataset - with 500 kb

thanks alot